# Show/Hide multiple WordPress entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have some code that pulls in wordpress posts, I want to just pull in the image. Then when the image is clicked, more info to appear in a div at the right side of the page. Been trying a few things myself but can't seem to get it to work correctly.

This is my wordpress code, i'm incrementing the posts to add showdiv-1, showdiv-2 etc... then incrementing the information div to be storeinfo-1, storeinfo-2 etc...

**Clickable logos:**

```
<ul class="store_list">
            <?php $i = 1; ?>
            <?php 
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            query_posts('cat=3'.$cat.'&order=ASC&showposts=100&paged=' . $paged);
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <li class="one-third nomargin">

                    <a id="showdiv-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="store-logo" title="View <?php echo $post->post_title; ?> shop info"><?php
                    $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Store Logo', true);
                    echo wp_get_attachment_image($thumbnail_id, 'Store Logo');
                    ?></a>

                </li>

                <?php $i++; ?>
                <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <p><?php _e('No shops to view in this category.'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
```

**Divs to show when logo is clicked:**

```
<?php $m = 1; ?>
        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        query_posts('cat=3'.$cat.'&order=ASC&showposts=100&paged=' . $paged);
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div id="storeinfo-<?php echo $m; ?>">
            <h1 class="shop-name"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h1>
            <p class="shop-telephone nop">Tel: <?php getCustomField('Telephone'); ?></p>               

            <div class="shop-openinghours">
                 <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
            <p class="shop-website nop"> <a target="_blank" href="http://<?php getCustomField('Website'); ?>">Visit Site</a></p> 
            </div>

        <?php $m++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p><?php _e('No shops to view in this category.'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with following steps;

You have already give ids, ok. Those images are related to specific information divs.(I assume store-info-* divs are hidden first). Simply write a jquery function. I am giving your updated code, and my new implemented jquery code.

**EDIT:** In order to hide previous ones when you click show info, I have added a class to store-info-* divs and added jquery code to my implementation to hide all open stores and show clicked one.

```
<ul class="store_list">
<?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts('cat=3'.$cat.'&order=ASC&showposts=100&paged=' . $paged);
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <li class="one-third nomargin">

        <a id="showdiv-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="store-logo" title="View <?php echo $post->post_title; ?> shop info" class="images"><?php
        $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Store Logo', true);
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($thumbnail_id, 'Store Logo');
        ?></a>

    </li>

    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('No shops to view in this category.'); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>



<?php $m = 1; ?>
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts('cat=3'.$cat.'&order=ASC&showposts=100&paged=' . $paged);
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div id="storeinfo-<?php echo $m; ?>" style="display:none;" class="stores">
<h1 class="shop-name"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h1>
<p class="shop-telephone nop">Tel: <?php getCustomField('Telephone'); ?></p>               

<div class="shop-openinghours">
     <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<p class="shop-website nop"> <a target="_blank" href="http://<?php getCustomField('Website'); ?>">Visit Site</a></p> 
</div>

<?php $m++; ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('No shops to view in this category.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".images").on('click', function() {
        $(".stores").hide();
        var idObj = $(this).attr("id").split("-");
        var id = idObj[1];
        $("#storeinfo-" + id).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Hüseyin BABAL, many thanks for this. It does work to add the div, although it doesn't hide the previous one. How can I do this? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I have added `.store` class to store-info divs and used it to js part. See my updated answer.